# Xcode 7.3 - Throwing "directory not found for option" Even if The Directory Did Exists

Tags: xcode

I am getting this warning a couple of times stating that the library directory is not found. I've tripled check the directory, and **IT IS THERE**. I tried to clean the project but still didn't work.

The strange thing is, when I remove the library(The whole folder) and copy-paste a new one, it will work - What I mean here is I deleted the source file from the main directory of the project and copy-paste a new one from another directory, then I will add the files to the project.

But after building a project for a couple of times without editing the directory or the contents of the library, this error will happen again.

It's like, when I fix this problem, it will be OK for now, but when I rebuild the project next time without editing anytime, the error will occur again.

I am not sure if this case has something to do with path containing spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing the space within the directory name. My directory name before was **Name Name**, Then I changed to **NameName**. Now the problem is gone. It's really strange, I don't think spacing would produce such problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying and pasting the directory you should: File > Add Files ... to your project. Xcode is likely losing the reference to it because the files are not "added" to the project.

Comment: sorry, I think what I said was not clear. I edited my question. I didn't just copy-paste the source directly to the project. I did it to the project's folder and then added them in Xcode just like what you said.